# Trying to run a Brownie Dapp in Docker

Tags: python, solidity, decentralized-applications, brownie, openzeppelin

I'm trying to run my brownie dapp in a docker container, but i always have the same error and can't seem to fix it:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/username/.brownie/packages/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-> > contracts@4.4.2/contracts/access/Ownable.sol'
```

I cloned the OpenZepplin folder with all the contracts to the work folder of my project and then remapped it like this:
dependencies:

```
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.4.2
compiler:
solc:
remappings:
      - "OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.4.2/ = ./OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.4.2/"
```

But it still gives the same error, and when I compile the contract, it is clearly still using the *C:/Users/username/.brownie/packages/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.4.2/contracts* folder. I know this because I tried to compile the contracts with a remapping to a non-existing folder:

```
remappings:
      - "OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.4.2/ = ./nothing/"
```

and it still compiled perfectly.

Just wondering if anybody could help me with this, and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I just had the IDENTICAL issue as yourself. (I cloned a project and tried to run tests on my local machine, but got the same FileNotFoundError:)

But I managed to solve it.

1. First thing you need to have is Brownie itself (Obviously).
2. Second thing is installed OpenZeppelin packages inside Brownie.
   Here is a link on how to set that up: [@OpenZeppelin for Brownie](https://iamdefinitelyahuman.medium.com/using-openzeppelin-contracts-with-python-and-brownie-ff7053d63bbe)

But in short, you just need this command:

```
brownie pm install OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.4.2
```

**MAKE SURE IT'S THE VERSION OF @OpenZeppelin YOU NEED !!**

3.Final step is to go into your project's build/contracts directory and delete ALL `smartContract.json` files and then do `brownie compile` anew.

After that you can run test etc, it should work.

---

**IN DEPT EXPLANATION:**

---

The reason we were getting that error was because Brownie uses smartCotnract.json build files to run the tests, and to locate all of its own dependencies/packages. Those .json files also contain paths to all of it (including @OpenZeppelin package), and are generated during compile phase only if they don't already exist or the code had been edited in a specific contract. (That is why you need to delete them if you want for `brownie compile` to generate new ones)

Therefor if I compile it on my local machine and push those smartContract.json files to git, and you happen to clone all of it and run the compile/tests. It is highly unlikely it will work, as name-path on my local machine will differ. (Username is practically 100% bound to be different)